# Appending list to list in python: leetcode #46

Tags: python-3.x, list, append

I'm solving leetcode problems and got stuck with this code outputting something like [[], [], [] ... []]

```
class Solution:
    def permute(self, nums: List[int]) -> List[List[int]]:
        permutations = []

        def backtrack(path):
            if len(path) == len(nums):
                permutations.append(path)
                return

            for num in nums:
                if num not in path:
                    path.append(num)
                    backtrack(path)
                    path.pop()

        backtrack([])
        return permutations
```

I looked up the solution and the only diffeence was that I had to change `permutations.append(path)` to `permutations.append(path[:])`.
I was pretty sure I could append list to list. Why isn't it working?

Comment: `path[:]` makes a copy of `path` instead of appending the same object

Comment: i understand now. in my original code i was trying to append the same list while constantly changing it. thanks.